# MS Visual Studio 2010: _UzpVersion is requested by object file, but _UzpVersion@0 is exported by library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, name-mangling

I'm trying to build my project using MS Visual Studio 2010 with the Info-ZIP unzip library. When I inserted `UzpVersion()` call into the code, the linker failed saying:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _UzpVersion referenced in function _wmain

DUMPBIN shows that the library exports `_UzpVersion@0` (it was compiled with the same compiler). But the object file requests `_UzpVersion`. The function is declared as:

```
extern "C" {

const UzpVer * UzpVersion(void);

}
```

What is wrong with it? How to fix it? Sorry, I'm not proficient with Visual C++; I spent most of my time with GNU C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by myself.

The library is compiled with `__stdcall` calling convention, but does not declare exported functions as such. Visual Studio 2010 by default compiles a project with `/Gd` flag, that switches to `__cdecl` calling convention. Besides other, these calling conventions are also using different name mangling schemes for C functions.

You can read [details on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/46t77ak2.aspx).

For Info-ZIP library in particular, the issue is fixed by adding the following defines before including the `unzip.h` header:

```
#define EXPENTRY __stdcall
#define USE_UNZIP_LIB
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a linkage error. The compiler see's the declaration of UzpVersion, otherwise, it would have failed to compile. You need to make sure you've configured your project to include the .lib.

[image]

EDIT: Additionally, you said you're compiling it yourself. Make sure you're compiling the sources as C and not C++.